# Dynamically add sub id to iframe code

Tags: html, iframe, google-ads-api

How would i take a sub id from a destination url and have it dynamically inserted into an iframe code before the page or iframe is loaded?

this is the code i have at the end of my destination url

```
&subid=campaignname_{keyword}
```

this is the iframe code where i want the subid to dynamically insert before loading

```
<iframe border="0" frameborder="0" width="680" height="800" src="http://xxxxxxx.com?PublisherSubID=</iframe>
```

Comment: Seems like u need php code insert, or JS script..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Form your URL like this :: (with the `#` in there)

```
http://example.com/page.html?#subid=subid_{keyword}
```

Then use this jscript ::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tags = ["subid"];
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
        var param = GetURLParameter(tags[i]);
        if (param) {
            var subid = GetURLParameter('subid');
        }
    }

if(typeof(subid) != 'undefined' && dynimage != null && dynimage != '') {
    document.getElementById('subid-iframe').innerHTML = '<iframe border="0" frameborder="0" width="680" height="800" src="http://xxxxxxx.com?PublisherSubID=' + subid + '</iframe>"';
    }
});

function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
```

and insert your "subid" value into the iframe tag using innerHTML with a  .... something like this token:

```
<span id="subid-iframe"></span>
```

this may require a bit of tweaking ... it has worked for me. I know what you are trying to do.